# Deactivate a Customer in AX 2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

We are building an integration between CRM 2011 and AX 2012.
The connector works quite ok, but we don't want an inactive account to be modified in CRM when  some updates are performed in AX.

We would like to make the status change to reflect in AX.
Is there some inactive status in AX as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the CustTable.Blocked field.

AR-> Common -> Customers -> All Customers -> Credit and collections -> Invoicing and delivery on hold

This field uses the [CustVendorBlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/custvendorblocked.aspx) enumeration.

If this is not exactly what you need you might be better off creating new custom field.